# How can I retrieve Javascript array from its defining scope?

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm trying to return an array called mapOptions which should vary based on whether or not the user allows the browser to access the location.

Here's my code...

```
var mapOptions;

const locationGranted = (position) => {
    // Set the map options (centering and zoom level)
    mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center:{lat:position.coords.latitude,lng:position.coords.longitude}
    };
    console.log("Granted: " + JSON.stringify(mapOptions));
}

const locationDenied = () => {
    // Set the map options (centering and zoom level)
    mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center:{lat:39,lng:-94}
    };
    console.log("Denied: " + JSON.stringify(mapOptions));
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locationGranted, locationDenied);

console.log("Submitted: " + JSON.stringify(mapOptions));

// Instantiate a new map class
gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap'),mapOptions);
```

The console correctly logs the array as "Granted" or "Denied" respectively. But outside of the block, I can't seem to access the array. For example, when I log the "Submitted" portion the array is undefined. Therefore the mapOptions is not available upon instantiation of the google map.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: The geolocation API is *asynchronous*.  Your variable will be changed eventually, but the call to the position API returns immediately before the position is actually retrieved.